# How to make a button work on a custom view from .xib instantiated programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

The button works if I add the view via the Interface Builder but it doesn't work when I add the view programmatically.

.xib design:

[image]

My custom view class:

```
class customView: UIView {
    
    static let singleton1 = customView()

    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!
    
    @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
        
        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue // this is what the button should do
    }
    
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       commonInit()
       window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
   }
   
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       commonInit()
       window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
   }
   
   func commonInit() {
       let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
       viewFromXib.bounds = self.bounds
       addSubview(viewFromXib)
   }
```

This is the way I instantiate it:

```
@IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
            let playerview = customView.singleton1 
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview(playerview)
            playerview.tag = 100 
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(playerview)// yes it needs to be in the window
```

Not sure if my initializer is wrong or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load "customView" xib into its own init method. Try below.

- Replace commonInit() method with getView(frame:CGRect)->UIView

  class customView: UIView {

  ```
    static let singleton1 = customView()

    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!

    @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {

        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue // this is what the button should do

    }


   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

   }

    func getView(frame:CGRect)->UIView{

       let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
       viewFromXib.frame = frame
       return viewFromXib
   }
  ```

  }
- Replace showView() method

  ```
    @IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
       let playerview = customView.singleton1.getView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200))
       self.view.addSubview(playerview)
       playerview.tag = 100
       UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(playerview)
    }
  ```

Comment: I just tried the approach but the app crashes when I click on showView button with "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key newView". Removing the newView outlet solves it but I need the outlet

Comment: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key newView" because you have not give outlet connection to newView object. Go to the storyboard and connect outlet.

Comment: it's connected in the customView class in this line: @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!